# CKEditor and german quotes

Tags: ckeditor, quotes

Does someone know how I have to configure CKEditor to use german quotes like:„ ... “

Cause by default it is using quotes like: " ... "

Someone got an idea what I have to change to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean? Are those not simply characters that you write yourself as content? Or do you have some kind of blockquote CSS style that adds them? How are they quotes inserted? Because I don't know anything that automatically adds quotes in CKEditor.

Answer (score 1):

Use autocorrect plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/autocorrect)

config.autocorrect_doubleQuotes = "„“";